# Language design: How does evaluation of parsed expressions work in Haskell?

Tags: parsing, haskell, functional-programming, evaluation

I'm writing a simple language in Haskell but I'm having an issue in evaluating arithmetic and relational expressions. At first I wrote one evaluation function then I recognised that I would need separate functions to evaluate each aspect of my language. So I have an arithmetic evaluation function, a relational evaluation function, and then a general evaluation functions.

The issue arises from actually producing something to work with and I think this comes from not being able to relate my other eval functions back to my main eval function. However I'm not sure if I'm approaching the evaluation incorrectly or not. I believe that perhaps a function like 'foldl1' would more useful to implement into the evaluation. I first learned about this function from the Write Yourself A Scheme in 48 Hours Wikibook and it seems like it's infinitely more useful than evaluating each possible expression. I'm not sure how this would implementable in my current code as it stands unless I had a function for each expression. For example if I had an expression like "1 + 1", my current parser parses this as "1 Add 1" but if I were to go with foldl1, I could have a function that gets each part this expression and "folds" the operator over the arguments. Even if I were to merge my current evaluation functions with the idea of foldl1, I still foresee the problem in evaluating anything meaningful from it that isn't just an integer or a string.

Any direction or help would be appreciated.

Below I have included by datatypse and my evaluation functions:

```
data HenryVal = Atom String
              | String String 
              | Integer Integer
              | Bool Bool
              | Not HenryVal
              | Neg HenryVal
              | List [HenryVal]
              | Seq [HenryVal]
              | Assign String HenryVal
              | If HenryVal HenryVal HenryVal
              | While HenryVal HenryVal
              | Skip
              | ABinary ABinOp HenryVal HenryVal
              | BBinary BBinOp HenryVal HenryVal
              | RBinary RBinOp HenryVal HenryVal

data BBinOp = And | Or deriving (Show)
data RBinOp = Greater | Less deriving (Show)
data ABinOp = Add
            | Subtract
            | Multiply
            | Divide
              deriving (Show)

evalABinOP :: HenryVal -> ABinOp -> HenryVal -> HenryVal
evalABinOP (Integer a) Add (Integer b) = Integer (a + b)
evalABinOP (Integer a) Multiply (Integer b) = Integer (a * b)
evalABinOP (Integer a) Divide (Integer b) = Integer (a `div` b)
evalABinOP (Integer a) Subtract (Integer b) = Integer (a - b)

evalRBinOp :: HenryVal -> RBinOp -> HenryVal -> HenryVal
evalRBinOp (Integer a) Greater (Integer b) = if a > b then (Bool True) else (Bool False)
evalRBinOp (Integer a) Less (Integer b) = if a < b then (Bool True) else (Bool False)

evalStmt :: HenryVal -> [HenryVal]
evalStmt (Assign var val) = [val]

evalCond :: HenryVal -> Bool
evalCond (Bool cond) = if cond == True then True else False


eval :: HenryVal -> HenryVal
eval val@(Atom _) = val
eval val@(String _) = val
eval val@(Integer _) = val
eval val@(Bool _) = val
eval val@(Neg _) = val
eval val@(Not _) = val
eval (List [Atom "quote", val]) = val
eval val@(List _) = val
eval val@(Seq _) = val
eval (If cond a b) = if (evalCond cond) then (eval a) else (eval b) 
eval (Assign var val) = eval val
eval (Seq (Atom func : args)) = apply func $ map eval args
eval (ABinary op x y) = evalABinOP x op y
eval (RBinary op x y) = evalRBinOp x op y
```

Error Messages:

```
./hask "[4 + 4]"
"No match: "Henry" (line 1, column 4):
unexpected "+"
expecting space, "(", "if", ";Do", "skip", identifier, letter, digit, "\"" or "[""
```

Write Yourself A Scheme in 48 Hours: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Write_Yourself_a_Scheme_in_48_Hours/Evaluation,_Part_1

Comment: It looks to me like you are doing just fine. You've successfully related your specialized evaluation functions back to your main evaluation function. What are you looking for help with? I don't see any way that foldl1 will magically solve your problems - maybe some more general notion like a catamorphism could help, but it seems a bit tricky since your List constructor needs special-casing, where the point of cata is that it does all the recursion for you.

Comment: I suppose what I don't understand is making it do stuff for the lack of a better term. I'm not sure how to go about relating an arbitrary expression back the evaluation function and getting the result of what I want. For example I can declare a number but say squaring the number leaves me with an error which says the operator is unexpected.

Comment: Include the exact inputs that cause the error, and the error itself, so that we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: @DanielWagner I added the error there!

Comment: The error message you've posted is being generated by the parser, not your evaluation functions.  So, there's something in your parser code that doesn't expect a `+` symbol at this position.

Comment: You added the error, but definitely not the code that's producing it. This badly needs a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) -- as it currently stands, it is unanswerable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure using `foldl1` would help you much here.  In the "Write Yourself a Scheme" wikibook, the `foldl1` function is used for the very specific purpose of applying "binary" functions like `+` and `-` to lists of arguments that might be of length > 2.  In Lisp, `(+ 1 2 3)` means the same thing as the Haskell expression:

```
foldl1 (+) [1,2,3]
```

so for this *specific* purpose, `foldl1` is a nice way to evaluate Lisp arithmetic expressions.  If you had a `HenryVal` constructor that looked like `ABinary ABinOp [HenryVal]` and you wanted the same folding behavior for your *list* of arguments, then you might have a use for `foldl1`.

So, how do we fix the problem you're running into.  If I can hazard a guess, I think you're probably looking at an expression like:

```
ABinary Add (ABinary Add (Integer 1) (Integer 2)) (Integer 3)
```

and realizing that your evaluator can't handle it because `evalABinOp` doesn't have any cases for when one of the arguments is another `ABinary` instead of an `Integer`, right?

Well, the trick is to use recursion.  In `evalABinOp`, recursively evaluate the arguments, make sure they're integers, and *then* do the arithmetic.  So, something like:

```
evalABinOp :: HenryVal -> ABinOp -> HenryVal -> HenryVal
evalABinOp e1 op e2
  = let Integer v1 = eval e1
        Integer v2 = eval e2
    in Integer $ calc v1 op v2
  where
    calc a Add b = a + b
    calc a Multiply b = a * b
    calc a Divide b = a `div` b
    calc a Subtract b = a - b
```

and then, after adding a `deriving (Show)` instance to `HenryVal`, you can seE:

```
> eval $ ABinary Add (ABinary Add (Integer 1) (Integer 2)) (Integer 3)
Integer 6
```

**As an alternative** that just occurred to me, you could keep your original definition of `evalABinOp`, as is:

```
evalABinOp :: HenryVal -> ABinOp -> HenryVal -> HenryVal
evalABinOp (Integer a) Add (Integer b) = Integer (a + b)
evalABinOp (Integer a) Multiply (Integer b) = Integer (a * b)
evalABinOp (Integer a) Divide (Integer b) = Integer (a `div` b)
evalABinOp (Integer a) Subtract (Integer b) = Integer (a - b)
```

and instead modify the corresponding `eval` case to make it recursive:

```
eval (ABinary op x y) = evalABinOp (eval x) op (eval y)
```

This would have the same effect.

Comment: Aside: I think it's a bit nicer to reorder the arguments to `calc`: `Integer $ calc op v1 v2 where calc Add = (+); calc Multiply = (*) ...`

Comment: This definitely solves the issue involving arithmetic. If I could ask, is there a massive difference between your evalABinOp and my own? I'm assuming yours is different in that in recursively evaluates the arguments whereas mine just assumes there's two integers being operated upon. Following your comment though that it's the parser causing the problem and not strictly the evaluator...I think I need to go back to see where my parser is breaking down.

Comment: No, there's not a massive difference.  They're quite similar.  In fact, I added an alternative solution that has the same effect but keeps your `evalABinOp` unchanged.

Comment: That's great to hear! I may change it to yours however because it's a lot clearer, at least to me on what is actually happening.